# Float left not working when used nth-child

Tags: html, css, web, css-float

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel=stylesheet href='scarychildselector.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}

div:nth-child(1){
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}

div:nth-child(2){
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Output in chrome:

[image]

I thought that the two green boxes will be in the left and the two red boxes will be in right of the window in an up-to-down manner

The problem here is that the last div floats to left instead of floating to right I'm confused what's the reason for floating to left? background-color property works fine and gives the div red color but the float property is'nt working. 
I just want to know why my code is behaving like that and why that box does'nt floats to the right

Comment: The last div is floating right, there are no elements above it, so it is in the top right, the first div wrapped inside your div nth(1) is floating left, since there are two divs already positioned it floats under them, or am I completely misunderstanding your diagram?

Comment: @Ryanwilson that is not a diagram it is a screenshot of chrome

Comment: use nth-child(2n) and (2n+1) instead of 1 and 2

Comment: With the given CSS and markup, it behaves as it is supposed to. Edit your question how you've been asked to, and you'll get a proper answer.

Comment: @LGSon I think now the question is correct or should I add some more detail in it

Comment: No code as image, post the actual code.

Comment: @LGSon but that code is actual code I wrote that just before asking the question

Comment: Yes, but you are still supposed to show it _in text form_ (so that other people could for example easily copy&paste it to set up their own example/ test version, if that was necessary), and not just “screenshots of code”. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Yes, but here at SO we don't want images with code, we want the code as text

Comment: Noticed you edited your question...changed my downvote to an upvote, and voted for a reopen.

Comment: @LGSon why my question is flagged. I readed all the advices by stackoverflow. I think there is nothing wrong in my question it is totally clear now

Comment: @user9218974 It were initially put on hold as you posted your code as an image instead of as text. Now, after you fixed that, I started with voting to reopened it, and 3 more have done so too, so it is one vote away to be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and float actually work the same way as it was meant to be. The issue was in your understanding. What I am adding below is not a solution. I was trying to explain the way it works. Please check. Check the code now and comment the `width: 150px;` and run again, so that you will understand the difference.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 150px; //Comment this line
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

In order to align both the green boxes on one side and the red boxes on the other side, you need to give `width: 100%` to the wrapper (The line you commented) and just comment the `margin: 10px`. You can see it like below.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

You were mistaken in giving width to the `.wrapper` and since all the divs were of width 50px, the child divs will break into two lines. But floating was perfect. That's what I tried to illustrate in the first example.

Comment: @LGSon: when we use float left to `nth-child(1)`, the inner div of the `.wrapper` is also another first-child. So the style will apply for that too. He was mistaken in giving width to the `div` which applies to the `.wrapper` also, so both the child divs wont fit in a single line and that will break into a new line. But floating was working perfectly. So that I asked to change the width of `.wrapper` and thus he found the difference. Thanks